# c# reportviewer visual studio 2012 express

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I've been trying to use the reportviewer control which is integrated to the visual studio 2012 express edition but I can't figure out how. I need to access a mysql database, get the data I want and present them on a table that can be printed. All the tutorials that I've found involve adding a new item to the solution - a report - but the report template is not supported by the express edition. Is there any way to circumvent this obstacle? Can I create this item manually? How? (C# winforms) 
Edit: I'm rephrasing the question a bit, because nobody answered so far. I have a datatable object (after sending a query to the database). How can I send the datatable to the reportviewer control and see the results on the screen?

Comment: You might be able to go around the reports by exporting your data into an Excel file and printing it from there. This is a much slower solution, but if you don't find a way to add reports to your project, it might be an option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it's not helping me... I can do the export but I want to learn how to use the reportviewer.

Comment: In that case, try to find a tutorial that will help you create the report programatically, but that is a very complicated procedure. I've tried to use it once, and failed, but you might have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

follow  this steps in this link even  the are in vb.net
 [How to use Report Viewer with Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?717175-How-to-use-Report-Viewer-with-Visual-Studio-2012-Express)
after that  go  to desiner.cs of your form  and add this line of code  whith similar cods in in bottom of the file

```
  // Form1
  // 
.
.
.      
   this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);
```